# Buyback preferred stock

Tags: stocks

Suppose I make a deal with a seller of a rental property to lend me $300,000 to finance through preferred stock in an Inc. Principle of buy-back.

1- Why are these preferred shares considered equity and not debt in my liabilities? I don't understand the basic reason why this is the case.

2- I discussed with my accountant. He explained to me that even if the seller financed me through this type of action, it is still possible for the bank to consider it as a debt if I ever decided to refinance my building, for example. I understood his point since if I take out $3000 each month to quietly buy back his shares, there is a good chance that the bank will ask me what is this $3000 that has been coming out each month for X time. Is there a workaround to convince the bank that this is equity and not debt.

Comment: Side note to my answer - 'convincing the bank that... [something is not what it is in reality]' is called 'fraud'. Be open and honest with the bank. They are very familiar with people trying to pull the wool over their eyes, and the consequences for them finding out after the fact that you have defrauded them would be very unpleasant.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variety of terms that don't fully align with eachother, and that may be part of the problem. If someone 'loans you money', by definition, you owe them a debt. That is what a 'loan' is.

If instead you offer to provide someone with preferred shares in your company in exchange for property, you are likely not under direct obligation to pay them back. What a 'preferred share' is exactly will depend on the terms included in that share certificate; perhaps it requires annual dividends if dividends are to be paid out to common shareholders, perhaps it has some rights to liquidate in certain circumstances, and perhaps it even has the right to be converted to legal debt in certain circumstances.

For legal purposes, equity is equity and debt is debt, often despite economic reality of what it entails.

For accounting purposes, the nature of the share class will determine whether it is classified as debt or equity. For a bank considering loaning you money, they care more about the economic solvency of you / the investment, than the accounting treatment.

For the bank's purposes, it doesn't matter what the legal or accounting definition of the arrangement is, they care about the economic substance of how it might impact them in the event that you fail to pay off your mortgage. The fact is, if your 'preferred stock' is actually close enough to debt that someone would consider it valid compensation for selling you a property, then the bank is likely to consider it the same way. Further, even if there are minimal ways that you could be forced to liquidate unilaterally by the PS holder, the bank probably doesn't want to get involved.

It is very clear that you are trying to do some type of financial maneuvering to get around some type of liquidity or viability test by orchestrating things in a certain way - and for just a $300k loan, it is unlikely any bank would be willing to perform the legal due diligence to confirm that the security you are offering is really worth what you say it is. They would simply fear that the PS holder would get paid out leaving them holding a worthless corp accountable for debt that it could not possibly repay.

Comment: Also note - typically when working with tiny 1-person corps, a bank will want the owner of the corp to personally guarantee any mortgage offered - they bank wants you to be personally invested with the success of the project, and they know that solely making the agreement with the corp would cause them a loss if the the corp goes bankrupt.

Answer (score -1):

> 1- Why are these preferred shares considered equity and not debt in my liabilities? I don't understand the basic reason why this is the case.

They're not. They're equity in a corporation, but you're not a corporation. So you have negative basis in the corporation in the amount of the $300K since you own it (or promised the buyback from whoever owns it through the preferred shares), but someone else put the money for it. Hence - it's a liability for you. *You* made a promise to buy the shares back.

> Is there a workaround to convince the bank that this is equity and not debt.

No. Because it is not.

Comment: If you own a corp, and someone is foolish enough to give you a property worth $300k in exchange for preferred shares of dubious value, then it is still not a personal liability for you - there is definitional limitation of liability to the owners of a corp, such that its owners are not liable for the corp's debts [in general].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon that's not how I understood the situation. I understood it as OP making a commitment to buy back the preferred shares in return to the property - that is most definitely a liability to the OP, not to the corporation.